# How to assign value to following container?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

Can anybody tell how to initialize the following container?
The key is fixed and the following two columns of information should be accessed according to the key and should possible to update during iteration:

Can anybody tell me how to access the variable sized columns in the following map container?

```
map<unsigned int, vector<vector<unsigned int>> > polyMap;



0                0                   20
                 1                   30 
                 2                   40
                 .                    . 
              face(n)           some angles

2                0                   20
                 1                   30 
                 .                   .
              face(m)           some angles

.                .                      .
.                .                      .
.                .                      .
.                .                      .
(`k vertex) (curesponding faces) (and angles)`
```

Hello all, it looks like my question is incomplete: Here is the thing, I have the vertex number(which is uniq=key) and faces around this vertex and respective angles: an example is shown below

Can you tell me whether its possible to make a map container as shown in the question for above purpose?

Comment: initialize? what do you mean? This will be default initialized, if you want something else you need to tell. Access columns? What did you try and how does it fail?

Comment: `... polyMap{ {key1, {{1,2},{3,4}}}, {key2, {{5,6},{7,8}}} };`

Comment: Isn't `pm[0][0][0] = ...` working for access?

Comment: @pergy not unless the vectors are resized or something has been pushed into them

Comment: @pergy:  It shouldn't.  You'll need `pm[0].resize(1); pm[0][0].push_back(...);`

Comment: @tobi303 @Martin Oh, I just used `0` as example. I meant that OP should just use bracket operator to access elements. Pushing and resizing is required, indeed, thanks.

Comment: Why do you use such a data structure that you don't understand?

Comment: @Jackyone Please [edit] your question to add additional information, rather than bury that in the comments.

Comment: Yes I have edited it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  // Declare initialized polyMap
  map<unsigned int, vector<vector<unsigned int>> > polyMap
  {
    { 11,
      {
        { 1,2 }, { 3,4 }
      }
    },

    { 22,
      {
        { 5,6 }, { 7,8 }
      }
    }
  };

  // add another element dynamically
  polyMap.insert(pair<int, vector<vector<unsigned int>>>(
    { 33,
      {
        { 9, 10 },{ 11, 12 }
      }
    }
    ));


  // check expected outcome for some values 
  assert(polyMap[11][0][0] == 1);
  assert(polyMap[11][0][1] == 2);
  assert(polyMap[22][1][1] == 8);
  assert(polyMap[33][1][1] == 12);
}
```

Comment: This looks satisfying result... thanks a lot @Michael Walz

Comment: @Jackyone if you find this answer useful please upvote/accept it so others know it was useful.

Comment: @Jackyone no, you haven't. You need to click on the green outlined checkmark at the top of the answer. Take the [tour].

Comment: @Jackyone : Err, no you haven't.  At least, your upvote won't be displayed to anyone else because you don't have enough reputation; what you *can* do, is "accept" the answer.  Click the grey tickmark under up/down-vote buttons.  This will turn in green, and marks the answer as "accepted"